# How many instances of same jmx file can we run in parallel in non gui mode

Tags: concurrency, jmeter

I have a jmx file that contain a property called FILE_NAME 
Now in non gui mode if i run same jmx file in say 20 instances with separate FILE_NAMES in parallel will it work

I have tried with 2 it is working, but want to make sure that it works with large number of instances in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by instance you mean JVM, then yes there is no problem provided the value of property is difference per instances.

Note you can pass property from command line using:

> -JFILE_NAME=value

And get it in JMeter using [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function:

> ${__P(FILE_NAME)}